# Image upload is not working in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, backend

I am building a web app using Spring Boot and I need the user to upload image. I am stuck at the backend of this problem. I have written the following code in controller. The app is running fine and when I upload the file through postman, it returns the image URL with status 200(ok) but the file does not get added to the folder.
Please suggest what is wrong here. Please keep it as detailed as possible.

Here's my code to upload image that I have written in the controller

```
@PostMapping("/image/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String message = "Image is successfully uploaded";
        try {
            String uploadPath = staticDir+"testfile_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"_"+file.getOriginalFilename();
            file.transferTo(new File(uploadPath));
            message = "Image URL : " + uploadPath;
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception occurred: {}",e);
            message = "Could not upload the file: " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(message);
        }

    }
```

I have annotated staticDir with @Value to get it's value from application.properties

```
@Value("${static.dir.path}")
    private String staticDir;
```

> application.properties
> `static.dir.path=C:\Users\rjuna\IdeaProjects\visitor-management-system\images`

Then I have a configuration for application to access the image through port 8080.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig  implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Value("${static.dir.path}")
private String staticDir;

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
          .addResourceHandler("/vms/**")
          .addResourceLocations("C:/Users/rjuna/IdeaProjects/visitor-management-system/images/");
}
}
```

"/vms/**" is a pattern. App will find any file of URL with this pattern in the location given just below the pattern. Now I am searching with this URL

```
localhost:8080/vms/testfile_1681807188450_My_Photo.jpg
```

But I am getting 404- Not found, both in the browser and postman. The API returns the image URL which is the file location in my computer. Though I want to access the image through the application i.e. through localhost:8080 and that is not working. Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Remove `@EnableWebMvc` as that will disable large parts of the web autoconfiguration for Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is being written to the incorrect location because of a missing path separator / or \.

Either

```
        String uploadPath = staticDir+"/testfile_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"_"+file.getOriginalFilename();
```

Or

```
static.dir.path=C:\Users\rjuna\IdeaProjects\visitor-management-system\images\
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It solves a part of the problem. Now, the image is getting uploaded to the folder. The API returns the image URL which is the file location in my computer. Though I want to access the image through the application i.e. through localhost:8080 and that is still not working. I am getting 404 Not found. I have updated the second half of the problem with configurations. Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: You’re going in the right direction with resource handlers. I would build a separate project based on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources  until it serves files and then pull the working functionality into your main project.